# Background image on body does not repeat (ng-view)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-view

Im having some problems with my Angular SPA. The background image on the body stops in the middle of the page.

My index.html

```
<body>
    <div ng-view autoscroll="true"></div>
</body>
```

My style.css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    padding-top: 80px;
    background: url("../img/bg-blue.jpg") repeat-y;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJuXb.png)

Here is a screenshot of the body height marked via Chrome console: [Screenshot with console mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6KqJ.png)

So the seems as the body can't get the height of the ng-view.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can put the background image on the `html` element instead, that would probably be the easiest solution.

Comment: remove the height:100% from html,body

Comment: @CBroe tried this, and the strange thing is the background is now at the bottom (where it was white before), but it's white at the top (where the bg was before)

Comment: @Araz This did not work.

Comment: @CBroe I now did the body background-color to white, and I placed the background to the html, and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
background: url("../img/bg-blue.jpg") 100% 100%;
```